# Actually not able to acces 2nd object in react

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

import Card from "./Card.jsx";
import contacts from "./contacts";

function App(){

    return(<div>
        <h1 className="Heading">My contacts</h1>
        <Card name={contacts[0].name}
           img={contacts[0].imgURL}
          tel=  {contacts[0].phone}
          email={contacts[0].email}
         />
         <Card name={contacts[1].name}
           img={contacts[1].imgURL}
          tel=  {contacts[1].phone}
          email={contacts[1].email}
         />
          
    </div>);
}
  export default App;

const contacts=[
    {
        id:0,
        name:"Siya",
        imgURL:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593504891806-cc4c04398e7c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        phone:"+556666565",
        email:"p@beyonce"
    
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:"Riya",
        imgURL:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594638739414-f21af9a25dba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        phone:"+556666565",
        email:"p@beyonce"
    
    },
    
];
export default contacts;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your  code properly

Comment: I fixed your code and inlined your images, but please read [ask]. You can't just dump code and screenshots here. You need to ask a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why don't you try iterating the constants like this, change HTML tags based on your requirement. But this work for you

```
    const cards= contacts.map((item, index) =>
      <div key={index}>
            <Card name={item.name}
                  img={item.imgURL}
                  tel=  {item.phone}
                  email={item.email}
            />
      </div>
      );
```

then in your return try

```
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <div>
          <h1 className="Heading">My contacts</h1>
          <div>{cards}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go for the function **map**, using this function you can show your items without needing to "build" them manually one by one.

For more infos i`m gonna leave the link for the method below:
[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp#:~:text=The%20map()%20method%20creates,for%20array%20elements%20without%20values](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp#:%7E:text=The%20map()%20method%20creates,for%20array%20elements%20without%20values).

I don't know why the second item isn't showing, but maybe because it is not clear if it is showing a error, not rendering infos about the contacts list or anything else.

If it helps, I changed your manually build of the list using map, it will do the same thing and i think maybe it will correct your problem, just give it a try hahaha :)

```
import React from 'react';

import Card from "./Card.jsx";
import contacts from "./contacts";

function App(){
return(
 <div>
    <h1 className="Heading">My contacts</h1>
    {contacts.map((contact, index) =>
      <Card
      key={index}
      name={contact.name}
      img={contact.imgURL}
      tel={contact.phone}
      email={contact.email}
      />
    )}
 </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

In this case, it will **map** (`.map((contact, index) => ...`, contact is the name that I gave to each contact of the list Contacts and index is the position of the `contact` in `Contacts`, `Contacts[0]` for example) and will render for every Contact in the Contacts a `<Card />` with the infos from each `contact`.